# Wake on lan only works after Start -> Shutdown

Tags: windows, shutdown, wake-on-lan

Does anyone know why when I use wake on lan it only works if I shutdown the computer through Start -> Shutdown, but if I use the shutdown -f command (as I do in a batch file after a system backup), the computer does not turn on through WOL. Is there some kind of prerequisite command that has to be done before the shutdown command?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be forcing drivers to shut down too quickly, leaving your hardware in a wonky state.

Try using `shutdown /s /t 0` instead, which is equivalent to Start > Shutdown

Note: `/t 0` won't force the stop of any processes, but does tell it to shut down immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try using /t 60 instead in order to give running applications 60 seconds to close out instead of being forced to close with no warning.  /f is implied when /t is used with a number greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's 10 years later, but I found a solution to the same problem:

```
shutdown /s /t 0 /hybrid
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown