# Windows 10 PC fails to wake via WOL after a shutdown from the Start menu option but works after a BAT shutdown method, why?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, shutdown, wake-on-lan

My Windows 10 Dell Latitude E6500 laptop PC fails to wake up via a wake on LAN magic packet after it had been shutdown via the shutdown option from the Windows10 Start menu.  However if I shut it down via a BAT script 'SHUTDOWN -s' command, then when I do a WOL magic packet it will wake up just fine.

Why would a shutdown via the Win10 Start menu cause a future WOL wake up attempt to fail?

What is the difference between that and a 'SHUTDOWN -s' command?  and would that difference be the reason for WOL not working?

I keep Windows 10 up to date so it has the latest patches as of this posting.

Comment: Does disabling Fast Startup make a difference?

Comment: _Fast Startup_ is enabled but unsure is a factor since WOL works after the laptop was shutdown via `shutdown -s`. According to [this post about WOL oddities](http://superuser.com/questions/276971/wake-on-lan-only-works-after-start-shutdown) a Windows Start menu shutdown is different than a `shutdown -s` command in that the former is immediate and may result in your machine getting in a wonky state impacting its ability to handle future WOL reqs. The `shutdown -s` command I use in a BAT has a 60s delay so I think my old laptop has time to cleanly shutdown and so is ready for future WOL reqs.